# I was trying to install gitit but during compile phase got this error

Tags: centos

```
Building library for gitit-0.12.3.1..
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -ltinfo
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

--  While building package gitit-0.12.3.1 using:
      /root/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1 build lib:gitit exe:expireGititCache exe:gitit --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: You have a much better chance of getting an answer  if you *[ask a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).*

Answer (score 3):

`/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -ltinfo` usually means you don't have a required library installed. That'd be the "tinfo" library, "libtinfo". On CentOS, that should be part of an ncurses package. Make sure you have the ncurses-devel package installed.